# Button does not function inside custom UI Control

Tags: swift, custom-controls

```
textFieldContainer.addSubview(showHideButton)
showHideButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

showHideButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textFieldContainer.topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
showHideButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.trailingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true

showHideButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "eyes-open"), for: .normal)
showHideButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(closeEye), for: .touchUpInside)
```

```
@objc func closeEye() {

    print("button pressed")

    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, options: [], animations: {
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.25) {
            self.showHideButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "eyes-open"), for: .normal)
        }
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.25, relativeDuration: 0.75) {
            self.showHideButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "eyes-closed"), for: .normal)
        }
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

The button does nothing when pressed, I have even tried putting a print statement inside to print to the console when tapped but nothing happens.

Comment: Try adding a sender to the method declaration:  `@objc func closeEye(_ sender: UIButton) {` and update the selector:  `#selector(closeEye(_:))`

Comment: @clawesome It still does not seem to be working. I am using a UIControl class, if that makes any difference this is not in the main view controller.

Comment: @clawesome here is the link to my git hub repo https://github.com/LambdaSchool/ios-sprint-challenge-password-textfield

Comment: https://github.com/kelson99/ios-sprint-challenge-password-textfield sorry wrong link @clawe

Comment: Your constraints seem to be the problem, your PassworldField's actual size is much smaller than where it's subviews are being displayed.  If you add this line to your PasswordField's setup `self.clipsToBounds = true` you'll find that none of your controls will display, or if you give it a background color you won't see the color displayed.  Since your subviews are outside the controls bounds they aren't able to receive touches.